# Image Upload not working in Canvas without jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to make a photo editing app using **HTML5 canvas** and **Fabric.js**. I want to  **upload** an **image** from my computer to the canvas.

**Code:**

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Obtain a canvas drawing surface from fabric.js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('tinman');
var img = document.getElementById('imageLoader').files[0];
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    angle: 30,
    opacity: 0.85
 });

canvas.add(img);.
```

I'm using this **HTML** for file **upload**:

```
<input type="file" id="imageLoader"/>
```

I know **$(document).ready()** is trying to look for the image after loading but the canvas just doesn't work without that.

How can I use **Fabric** without using **jQuery** by using function **init().**

Answer (score 0):

First Solution

Call the `init` funtion when the body tag loads.

```
//HTML
<body onload="init()">

//JavaScript
fucntion init(){
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('tinman');
  var img = document.getElementById('imageLoader').files[0];
  var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      angle: 30,
      opacity: 0.85
  });
}
canvas.add(img);
```

Second possible Solution

Self invoking function this code below executes as soon a the page is loaded, and any code you put below this would be interpreted next.

```
(function(){
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('tinman');
  var img = document.getElementById('imageLoader').files[0];
  var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      angle: 30,
      opacity: 0.85
  });
})();
canvas.add(img);
```

Comment: Thank You! I got it now.